# Cannot overwrite model once RE-compiled Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js14

Cant re compile when making a change in the code, i have to manually stop the dev environment and then execute it again to see the changes made.

Im using nextjs 14.1.0

here is my code:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const waitListSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// const WaitList = mongoose.models.WaitList || mongoose.model("waitList", waitListSchema);
const WaitList = mongoose.models.WaitList ?? mongoose.model("waitList", waitListSchema);

export default WaitList;
```

Here is the error log

```
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `waitList` model once compiled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongoose.models` structure contains the models names as passed to the `mongoose.model` method, not the variable name they happened to be assigned to after creation.

Specifically, after calling `mongoose.model("waitList", ...)` and assigning the returned value to `const WaitList`, `mongoose.models.waitList` will be populated, but `mongoose.models.WaitList` will be undefined.

Any subsequent call to

```
const WaitList = mongoose.models.WaitList ?? mongoose.model("waitList", waitListSchema);
```

will attempt to call mongoose.model again, resulting in the error.

To fix this, match the case in the test to the model name as created:

```
const WaitList = mongoose.models.waitList ?? mongoose.model("waitList", waitListSchema);
```

`